# Where to find changes.sty without install texlive?

Tags: texstudio

I tried to use TexStudio compile a .tex file, and got "File `changes.sty' not found. ^^M".

I googled seems changes.sty is inside texlive, which is about ~8GB size. Is there any website I can download changes.sty? Thank you very much

Comment: which tex system are you using? (texstudio is only an editor).

Comment: Sorry, where to find this information..

Comment: It's on https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/-/tree/main/texmf/tex/latex/changes.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Check [TeX distributions](https://www.latex-project.org/get/) and the operational system of your computer. It seems you download TeXstudio without installing TeX. What have you tried to compile? Did some basic `Hello World` work before?

Comment: @FHZ If there is an error about a `.sty` file not being found then presumably LaTeX is installed but is just missing the package.

Comment: @Marijn thanks! It works! At least the tex file starts to ask other sty.

Comment: @FHZ thanks. There's other `.tex` file works.

Comment: In general I would advise to install the full TeX Live, 8GB might look like a lot but you probably have the space available and then you don't have to worry about missing packages anymore.